# Rename file to yyymmddhhmmss

Tags: linux, ssh

I have one file is `POLL91.DWN` then i want to rename `xxxx.yyyymmddhhmmss.POLL91` (xxxx is the store name) it will become

```
GSTD.20151223121805.POLL91
```

Comment: We need more context. I guess you don't just want to rename this one file once, right?

Answer (score 1):

`mv POLL91.DWN GSTD.20151223121805.POLL91`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10659466)

Comment: meta: Very short and I had originally put this as a comment, but AJ only specified a single file and the desired result, which this does provide. Should I remove my answer and put it back as a comment?

Comment: Haha, I love this answer! =D

Comment: Yes, but that will only work for a single file. Be very cautious with low-level programs under Linux because it is very easily to accidentally create or delete a lot of files. Try `man mv` to read more about how it works.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you can use [`date`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/date) and a format string like

```
mv "POLL91.DWN" "GSTD.$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S).POLL91"
```